# Simplistic Lava Lamp

Tags: code-golf, number, random, integer

### Introduction:

I think everyone knows what a Lava Lamp is, but in case they do not:

[image]
[<sup>(Image source)</sup>](http://api.ning.com/files/qrbliHRnvdw1Rjlr3hjMBmZV8cArQzQHkjqIHMFYV8KWdSCn2lBsAOS6i8s6TltTPjR1JKi9OOFVeYuHqDer7HzWmrvpdteJ/1614584823.gif?xgip=108%3A0%3A324%3A324%3B%3B&width=48&height=48&crop=1%3A1)

They're basically glass tubes that contain wax in a translucent liquid. The bottom part is heated when the lamp is turned on, causing a change in density and thus the wax floats to the top. When it cools down, it falls down again, causing the effect we see above.

It usually takes about 45-60 minutes for the base of the lamp to rise in temperature high enough to change the solid wax to liquid wax (if the lamp is located in an area at room temperature).

[More information on Wikipedia, which is also used as source for some of the text above.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lava_lamp)

### Challenge:

Given a positive integer `n` indicating the amount of minutes that have passed since we've turned the Lava Lamp on, output a random state of the Lava Lamp based on integers on five levels.

For this challenge we'll say the Lava Lamp contains 1000 units of wax in total, and we have five levels where the wax can be at.

1) If `n` is below 45, the Lava Lamp is still heating up, so the output will be four empty lines with `1000` at the bottom:

```
1000
```

2) If `n` is in the range `[45, 60)` the Lava Lamp has increased in temperature enough for wax to move around, but no very high yet. The wax can reach up to and including the third level.
3) If `n` is `60` or higher, the wax can be at any of the five levels.

So given the positive integer `n` as input, we'll output a [random](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1325/52210) state with the three rules above in mind.

**Here are some example outputs:**

Possible outputs for any `n` that is `>= 45`:

```
523
106
371
```

```
913

87
```

Possible outputs for any `n` that is `>= 60`:

```
73
113
312
5
497
```

```
284
55
637

24
```

Constant output for `n` that is `<= 44` (and possible output for any `n`):

```
1000
```

### Challenge rules:

- There can be empty lines, even though the level above it is not empty.
- Just `0` isn't allowed on any line. Should be empty instead.
- Output is somewhat flexible. You are allowed to output a list/array of strings/objects instead of a new-line delimited result as above. The reason I say strings/objects is due to the rule above. An empty line should be `""`, `null`, `[]`, etc., but cannot be `0` or a negative integer (nor can it be `false`) (I.e. `["", "", 913, "", 87]` for `n >= 45`). You are also allowed to reverse the output (I.e. `1000\n\n\n\n` instead of `\n\n\n\n1000` or `[87, null, 913, null, null]` instead of `[null, null, 913, null, 87]`).
- The numbers should all be integers. The can be decimals with `0` as decimal value, but none of the numbers should have any decimal digits, and the integers should always sum to exactly `1000`.
- All possible [random](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1325/52210) outputs based on `n` should have a non-zero chance of occurring.
- A trailing new-line (so there are six lines of output) is allowed.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

Comment: [Semi-related: "_Random numbers with fixed sum_"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165043/random-numbers-with-fixed-sum) and [Related stackoverflow answer for "_Random numbers that add to 100_"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8064754/1682559)

Comment: May an empty level be represented with a single space?

Comment: @Arnauld Sure. Can be anything except for `0`, a negative number, or `false`.

Comment: Is the output always 5 levels, even when `n < 60`?

Comment: @Emigna Yes, the output is always 5 levels. For `n < 45` only 1 level is filled however (top or bottom depending on the order you output it in), which is `1000`. With `45 <= n < 60` three of the five, and with `n >= 60` all five. But the output will always contain five 'lines'.

Comment: I assume it's not allowed, but it would be funny to bypass the `0` is an empty string by outputting in unary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
5º*♪{k[K∞╟(]m<Σ∞wΦ}σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/00C6tRzNXVWdHez/qmPdo6nyN2Fybc4uB7PJzy2rPN///b8BlYsJlYsplasllZsBlaGAAAA)

This is my first answer in my new language. I based my solution on Emigna's 05AB1E solution, but used some neat features of MathGolf to make it a tiny bit shorter.

### Explanation

```
5º*                   push 5, [0], multiply (yielding [0,0,0,0,0]
   ♪                  push 1000
    {                 start block
     k                push input as integer
      K∞              push 22 and double it, yielding 44
        ╟(            push 60 and decrease, yielding 59
          α           wrap last two elements in array, yielding [44,59]
           m<         map is less than, giving [0,0], [1,0] or [1,1]
             Σ        sum array, giving 0, 1 or 2
              ∞       double, giving 0, 2 or 4
               w      push random integer in range
                Φ     increase array element
                 }    execute for loop (loops 1000 times)
                  σ   convert to string and remove leading zeroes (implicit map)
```

Comment: If the features aren't builtins for this challenge in of itself, the non-competing tag won't be necessary. Since [mid last year](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges) non-competing is no longer a thing. Since it's very new I assume there isn't an online compiler for your language yet? Could you instead perhaps add some screenshots (or links to screenshots if it would clutter the post too much) as verification? And I would contact _@Dennis_' to ask if your language could be added to [TryItOnline](https://tio.run/#).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for the feedback! I'll add some screenshots, and I'm working on getting the language to TIO. I'll contact Dennis once I feel that I'm not constantly adding new features.

Comment: Have you considered [creating a room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) for your language? I'm very interested in learning it!

Comment: @JoKing glad to hear you're interested! I'll try to create a room sometime this weekend. I only just got the language on TIO thanks to Dennis, I'm working on making it accessible to everyone!

Comment: @JoKing [I created a room for MathGolf](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83257/mathgolf-the-language). I'll try to answer any questions as soon as I can, I know the documentation is a bit unfinished.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>117</s> <s>113</s> <s>108</s> <s>107</s> <s>106</s> 105 bytes

```python
from random import*
def f(n):a=['']*5;exec"i=randint(0,(n>44)+(n>59)<<1);a[i]=(a[i]or 0)+1;"*1000;print a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYyxDoMgFEV3v4K4yNMOiEq1aH/EOJAqkUEwhKH9evpkcTn35eS@e/7C7iyPUXt3EK/simGO0/lQZuumiaYWXmqai2IpO7l9t09upqtnbKDsQe27baHC6AYYxxqkms0y0YvOEwZVLfOyZozJ0@MLUVFTBpmmDTIpvHHiYpfY3x43kSL1Bb@94LwZ@vYJ8Q8)

Returns a reversed list (bottom first)

---

Version inspired by the stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8064754/1682559) in the comments (edgecases are more likely):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 129 bytes

```python
from random import*
def f(n):a=sorted([1000]*5+sample(range(1001)*5,(n>44)+(n>59)<<1));print[y-x or''for x,y in zip([0]+a,a)[:5]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBDoIwEEX3nKI7ZwCTUigCohchLJpAtYm0TWEBXh5HNmzen7zM/35b3s6KfdfBTSwoO1CYybuwxNEwaqbBYqMeM4lxgC7jnPexTGY1@c8IVHiNQDLDWKZgn0WBCYWssW0zxLsPxi7ddl2ZC5eLdoGt6caMZV/joeN9olKFXSP7ftfAMdKQE48W3bT2pzxYnZ7mieXxX4rTl0LkdVXccP8B)

Comment: I don't know exactly how your code work, but does every state have a non-zero chance of occurring? All your numbers are hovering near the `333` or `200` for the 3 or 5 parts respectively. I don't see any spikes/outliers towards `0` or `1000`. Or are the chances for those just astronomically small (but still non-zero) in comparison to integers near `333` and `200`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Each of the 1000 lava-units are put into a random bin (`0` or `0-2` or `0-4`), and counted.
The chances of none of then going into either is there, but very small.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. Now I also understand your code better already. Thanks! +1 from me.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 78 bytes

Returns a reversed array where empty levels are filled with a space.

```javascript
t=>(a=[...'     '],g=k=>k?g(k-1,a[Math.random()*(t>59?5:t<45||3)|0]++):a)(1e3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxNDoIwEEDhvadwx4xAA6E1Qmw5gScgLCb8KtgaaFz17lWXpm/5Ld6D3rR32/1lU236wY/SW6mAZMMYi46/ojaZ5CLVUk@wpHlCzY3szDbSvXkCnsAqUdaislcunCvQZW0cY0UI@VCg74zezTqw1UwwQoZ4@BfOQxIBiTKgc/i6fMl/AA)

#### Commented

```javascript
t => (                      // t = input
  a = [...'     '],         // a[] = output array, initially filled with 5 spaces
  g = k =>                  // g = recursive function taking an iteration counter k
    k ?                     //   if k is not equal to zero:
      g(                    //     do a recursive call:
        k - 1,              //       decrement k
        a[                  //       update a[]:
          Math.random() * ( //         pick a random slot:
            t > 59 ? 5 :    //           among all 5 slots if t > 59
            t < 45          //           force the 1st slot if t < 45
            || 3            //           among the 3 first slots otherwise
          ) | 0             //         round the above result to an integer
        ]++                 //       increment the wax amount on this slot
      )                     //     end of recursive call
    :                       //   else:
      a                     //     stop recursion and return a[]
)(1e3)                      // initial call to g() with k = 1000
```

Comment: I actually have the same question as [the comment I made for the Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171984/simplistic-lava-lamp?noredirect=1#comment415056_171985): Does every state have a non-zero chance of occurring?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Each state has a non-zero chance of occurring, but extreme values have a very low probability. If I did my maths correctly, you are ~\$10^{90}\$ times more likely to be [hit by a meteorite](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/2016/02/160209-meteorite-death-india-probability-odds/) than to get an intermediate empty slot in there. :p

Comment: Rofl, nice analogy with the meteorite. ;) I now indeed see that your method is similar to the Python answer in that it puts values in one of the 3 or 5 spots in the array, up to a count of 1000. Nice answer, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>85</s> 84 bytes

```r
function(n)write(ifelse(t<-table(cut(runif(1e3,2*(n<60)+3*(n<45),5),0:5)),t,""),1,1)
```

-1 byte thanks to @Giuseppe

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBCsMwDATvfUZOUquA3TQ5FH8mCRIIglpcmT7ftRtYhh12c5U0Vim2u74MDL9ZnUGFjw@Dp9HX7WDYi0MupgKRJ7pfwdIS8Db18piRWsJzRiSnYUCKFLG@s5pDwIt0nNa@TTtPX/5zY/0B)

Explanation (ungolfed):

```r
function(n){
      # Generate 1000 random uniform numbers in [5,5] (if n<45),
      # in [2,5] (if 45<=n<60) and in [0,5] (if n>=60).
    x = runif(1e3,2*(n<60)+3*(n<45),5) 
      # Code each by the number of the interval it falls in (0,1],(1,2]...(4,5]
    cx = cut(x,0:5)
      # Tabulate the intervals. Because cut() returns a factor,
      # zero counts are included 
    t = table(cx)
      # Vector-wise replace zero elements with "" and cat out, 1 per line.
    t1 = ifelse(t,t,"")
    write(t1,1,1)
}
```

Comment: If `NA` is allowed as empty line/element, here's a 77 byte solution ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT6fCtiQxKSdVozgxtwBIGVppGGlpaOTZmZhoagMpU0tNTW1DTR3DVGOdEE1Nzcy01JziVI0KnQodP0fNaEMr09j/BUWZeSUaBppcaSACwjMxBXFBJIRvBpYGkv8B "R – Try It Online")) or an 80 byte solution ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT6fCtiQxqTQnsSRVozgxtyAnVcPQSsNIS0Mjz87ERFMbSJlaampqG2rqGKYa64RoampmpqXmFKdqVOhU6Pg5akYbWpnG/i8oyswr0TDQ5EoDERCeiSmICyIhfDOwNJD8DwA "R – Try It Online")) if the element names are a problem

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>131</s>, <s>116</s>, <s>90</s>, <s>89</s>, 87 bytes

```c
L(l,a,v,A){for(A=5,v=1e3;A--;v-=a)printf("%d\n"+!a*2,a=l>59|A<3&l>44?rand()%-~v:!A*v);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7NUoMwFIX3PMVtHZwEEodacGxDcNi3T6AuYvhpahocoHFR8dGN0OqiuzPfPd@dI2ktpbtRRupjUULa9YVq7naZd4W0ertmvTqUI3EbpIkgluT4VDUtynlCLF@US5ZTyizlAn@0yvQVmvvFi5mHMxHcE8F1lqy@8nR5q7M4fmqFKRD26bddz/LAYja40YGDUAZNQbS1JHInWgiCMVsMJw@gO2tSN/IdYcxGMi2Y@opHDMJQpZPILm2A6bLnom8Ump48q9ezBPC/cKvMsS/BL9bjUgL7v/MGXdLgDc4tEhfHLk5csnIPkXuMfmSlRd05@vkL)

**Update**: Fixed a bug in the original. Fused in the helper function, reducing an additional 15 bytes.

**Update 2**: -25 bytes thanks to ErikF.

**Update 3**: -1 byte thanks to ceilingcat.

### Degolf

```c
L(l,a,v,A){
    for(A=5,v=1e3;A--;v-=a)
        printf("%d\n"+!a*2, // No clue how this works anymore, but it'll advance the pointer 
                            // to the string constant when a number shouldn't be printed.
        a=l>59|A<3&l>44?rand()%-~v // Random integer to print in [0, v]
        :!A*v); // If bottom layer, return remaining volume
}
```

Comment: You can eliminate the `puts()` by combining the printing into a single `printf()` and putting the subtraction into the loop end. Also, I think you're allowed to put the `srand()` initialization into the caller. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LUoMwGIX3PMXfOjgJBCe14IwNwWFfn0BdxEDb1DQ4hGbT4qtH0uqiuzPfucyR2VZKf6eM1MemhdIOjeoedlV0g7T6vGWDOrQT8WukiSCO1MTi06brkeUFcXxBKWU2y5jLuMA1n9mzrornsy2X97rKc/LdKzNs0Dxu3s08ndXJIxHcvtRJL0yDcJz9uJXDbPRTDA5CGRSE6LeSyJ3oIUkm7TCcIgB76UjdyS@EMZtIOBLyilMGaarKUGTXNEBw9lwMnUJh5E19XEoA/6delTkOLcTNajpHYP9nr9FVjdHo/aLwS@rzwj/RXw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: I realized that I missed the "no zeroes" restriction. Here's the fixed version: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LUoMwGIX3PMXfOjgJBCe14IwNwWFfn0BdxEDb1DQ4hGbT4qtH0uqiuzPfucyR2VZKf6eM1MemhdIOjeoedlV0g7T6vGWDOrQT8WukiSCO1MTi06brkeUFcXxBKWU2y5jLuMA1RzN71lXxfLbl8l5XeY6TXpgG4Tj7ceS7V2bYoHncvJt5OquTRyK4falXDrPRTx4chDIoCNFvJZE70UOSTNphOEUA9jImdSe/EMZsIuFKyCtOGaSpKkORXdMAwdlzMXQKhZE39XEpAfw/eVXmOLQQN6vpEYH9n71GVzVGo/eLwi@pzwv/RH8B "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: Some last tweaks! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7NUoMwFIX3PMW1Dk4CwUktOGNDcNjXJ1AXMdD21jQ4lGZT8dUjaXXR3Znv/MzR2UZrf4tWm2PTQnkYGuzut1V0hQx@XLMB9@1E/IoYpphjNT2tu57UsmBOzjnnos4y4TKpqJL1MzFV8fRdl4s7U@U5TXplG0Lj7MctHfvq0Q5rMoubNztLb1TywBQVo58o7BVaEoTqN5rpreohSSbtKJwigMN5SJtOfxJKxUTCi5BHyQWkKZahKC5pgODspBo6JGHkFd/PJYD/Dy9oj0MLcbOcvjDY/dkrclFjNHo/L/yC@7zwj/wX "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: Great; I golfed it down by an additional byte.

Comment: Also, we did it! We beat Python!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>27</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to *Adnan*.
Saved another byte thanks to *Kevin Cruijssen*.

```
5Å0₄FD„,;ÇI‹O·ÝΩ©è>®ǝ]ε0Û
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9vc2FiaWX//zXDhTDigoRGROKAniw7w4dJ4oC5T8K3w53OqcKpw6g@wq7HnV3OtTDDm///NTk)

**Explanation**

```
5Å0                         # initialize with a list of 5 zeroes
   ₄F                       # 1000 times do:
     D                      # duplicate the list
      „,;ÇI‹                # check if the input is larger than 44 and/or 59
            O·              # sum and double, yielding (0,2 or 4)
             ÝΩ             # pick a random number between and 0 and the number above
               ©è           # get the count in that level
                 >          # increment it
                  ®ǝ        # insert it at the same position
                     ]      # end loop
                      ε0Û   # remove leading zeroes on each level
```

Comment: Nice answer! I like the way you've used `5Å0` and `ǝ`, and `ε0Û` at the end. I tried to come up with something shorter, but I'm unable to. I have the feeling it can somehow still be golfed, but I'm currently not seeing it (perhaps it cannot and it's just a random feeling). `•A–•60в` is 1 byte longer than `44 59‚` instead of shorter. And `ε0Û` to replace the `0`s with empty strings also seems to be the shortest possible, since `0K` simply removes the 0-items completely and `0м` removes any digit `0` in all numbers.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Yeah I've looked and looked to find a shorter way of doing `44 59‚`, but I can't find it (`•H|•2ô` is the same count). My previous solution (also 27 bytes) used `45` and `60` which are easier to generate in different ways, but I think that was invalid as it output **1**, **3** or **5** levels depending on input and not always **5**.

Comment: Ah, `•H|•2ô` is indeed also a smart way, hadn't thought about that. And it should indeed output 5 lines. I saw your previous answer indeed and was about to comment it only outputted 1 line for `n < 45`, but then you deleted it. Glad you've found another 27-byte solution. :)

Comment: I think [`ŽH|2ô`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6F6PGqPDW/7/BwA) is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Adnan: Oh, nice. I didn't know about `Ž`, only `Ƶ`. Thanks :)

Comment: @Adnan Oh, never seen `Ž` used before either. Does that only apply to compressed integers as alternative for `•..•`? Or does it have some other use cases as well?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It acts exactly like that. Did some research using previous answers using 05AB1E and this was one of the things I added in the rewrite. It does not have any other use cases right now.

Comment: @Adnan I've edited my [05AB1E tip about compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to mention it as well. :)

Comment: -1 byte by changing `ŽH|2ô` to `„,;Ç`. Not sure why I hadn't thought about this before..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Oh yeah, that's smart. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>87</s> 86 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,w=1e3,s=5,r=n<45|n<60&s<4|s<2?w:Math.random()*w|0)=>s?`${r||""}
`+f(n,w-r,s-1):""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc7fCsIgHIbh812GRGjp2EoHLW1X0D1Mttkfloa/kQfZtRsdFsFOPx4@3qt@aOj85T4x6/ohJaOwpUGVw5aCEtQrK7mIVlbFEiSPIDdNqI96Oude297dMFmFWBB1gKZdPH2MCL2ydm0@L8xTYCWpEUr7rHMW3DjkozthgwtCvifyKzifJ2KWiN0sqf60pDc)

The 83-byte solution (`(n/15-2|0)*s<4`) is reserved first because I need to check for larger `n`.

UPDATE: Yeah, `(n/15-2|0)*s<4` didn't work because for larger `n` because `n` large enough makes the sum fail to reach 1000.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 92 bytes

```php
$i=5;for($n=1e3;$i--;$n-=$x)echo($x=rand($i?0:$n,$i<($argn<60?$argn<45?:3:5)?$n:0))?:"","
";
```

Run as pipe with `-R` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/218896eb2ea7e4780ca690544349f6ead123293c).

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>121</s> <s>117</s> <s>113</s> 111 bytes

```java
m->{for(int w=1000,j,i=5;i-->0;w-=j=i>0?j*=Math.random():w,System.out.println(j<1?"":j))j=m>59|m>44&i<3?w+1:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVA9T8MwEN3zK04ZUEIbyxWtBE2cDIiBgalsiMGkSXsmtiP70oBKf3twq4qJJ52edF/v3Sl5kJnafk51J72H18YTHKMIoB8@OqzBk6RAB4tb0BJNsiGHZvf2DtLtfAq0d3b08PRVNz2hNWEYAlRYywbCjrWDqc8F9miNH3TjimdDza5xJbQgYNJZeWytS9AQjGLBOZ@rOYpVjllW8nzMhBJY8krdihdJe@ak2VqdpOtxvvn21GhmB2J9MEWdSVSxqOJ4rdJUCV2uHn50uVzeYHFXjbPFmuenKY8uBoMkXDQxmOB5oALuLzwTsEqvZwD8oxFaIIbsD3GaX5tbJuvzHxK8pk7ROU7TLw)

It's biased towards putting more wax near the top, but it's theoretically possible for any legal arrangement of wax to appear.

edit: 4 bytes were saved by [@KevinCruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

## In Human-readable Java:

```java
(int minutes /* golfed variable m */) -> {
  int waxRemaining = 1000; // golfed variable w

  // golfed version goes from index 4 to 0 in a bit of a roundabout way
  // starting at 5 but decrementing right away
  for (int level = 4 /* golfed variable i */; level <= 0; level--) {
    // golfed variable j
    // the golfed version initializes this to (waxRemaining + 1)
    // in order to juice out some extra bytes during the Math.random() call
    int waxAtLevel = 0;

    // the golfed version does all of these ifs as ternary operations
    // and avoids using 2-character operators wherever possible
    // so e.g. "a == 0" becomes "a<1" and "a && b" becomes "a&b"
    // since here we are certain things can't be negative,
    // and took a good look at the Java operator precedence cheat-sheet
    // to make sure "&" and "|" would work properly to give a truthy value
    if (level == 0) {
      // if we are at the bottom level, just put the rest of the wax there
      waxAtLevel = waxRemaining;
    } else if (minutes >= 60 || (minutes >= 45 && level < 3)) {
      // otherwise if we are at a legal level put a random portion of the remaining wax there
      // note: the random portion can be between 0 and waxRemaining inclusive
      waxAtLevel = (int) (Math.random() * (waxRemaining + 1));
    }

    if (waxAtLevel > 0) {
      // only print the amount of way at this level if its greater than 0
      System.out.print(waxAtLevel);
    }
    System.out.println();

    waxRemaining -= waxAtLevel;
  }
}
```

Comment: `Math.random()*(w+1)` can be `Math.random()*-~w` for -2 bytes. [Here the relevant tip as reference why.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67630/52210). Nice answer! +1 from me. EDIT: Actually, 2 more bytes can be saved by using `j` temporary as variable for `w+1` (since it will be overwritten right after in the print anyway) and use `j*=Math.random()` instead so you won't need the cast to `(int)` ([117 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/y8h7fmhl)).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen nice! Also I just noticed that the `&i>2` condition isn't necessary

Answer (score 3):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 215 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Math.Random,Text
? ::!Int->Int
?_=code{ccall time "I:I"
}
$n#l=take(max(2*min(n/15-2)2)0+1)(genRandReal(?0))
#l=map toInt[1E3*e/sum l\\e<-l]
|sum l==1000=map(\v|v>0=v<+"\n"="\n")(l++repeat 0)%(0,4)= $n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY/BS8MwGMXv@StinZCsrUurXsqyXtyhoCCbNyvykWazmHwpXVYmzn/d2Orl8X7w3oOnjAYM1jVHo6mFFkNrO9d7uvXNGofkEfz79QawcTZ51idPSloUFxX6dDUKKd@kco3@UgqMob61mkZVUUXkm8zw0kgPH5pZOLF8bltkuMju0pznXMQZZ3uN0/JGg2Gl4JyMBQsd9W6cfsnWN3O9OBwtNXWtl6l5Jec/kjITQkxJVg/nYSXksIyjGiM5CWcmjnvdafBU8Csmklsu6QzD1sN4a7R0qocftTOwP4S0egj3nwi2Vf/wZMDvXG9/AQ)

So I've finally found a shorter way to get a random seed than importing `System._Unsafe`, `System.Time` and using `toInt(accUnsafe time)`...
And boy is it truly in the spirit of codegolf - embedding a call to C, ignoring the world state type normally used to ensure the evaluation order of such things.

Answer (score 3):

## [Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/), <strike>188</strike> 162 bytes

```
param($m);$t=0;$a=,0*5;$s=if($m-lt45){4}elseif($m-lt60){2}else{0};$s..4|%{$t+=$a[$_]=if($_-eq4){1e3-$t}elseif($t-ne1e3){Random(1000-$t)}}$a|%{if($_){$_}else{''}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLCsIwEEX3fsdIO2rKVNO6KPkJtyIl4IhC@rANuBjz7TFUdHvuPWccXjzNd3YuxtFOtsuhwwa8oQas2dGmamA2j1vCynldoejAbuYfqQllvxChkK5Fod9rAb81YM/QXha1VfzUKCUfFPi/7lXPCaGcbH8durwkorRjCCuwKbKYKNB@81kWQoyxPn4A)

-2 bytes by @Kevin Cruijssen
-4 bytes by removing optional Get- verb
-20 bytes by shortning loop and removing spaces

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! Great first answer! I did some basic testing, and everything seems to work great. I know barely anything about Powershell, but is it possible to change `else{if($t-ne 1e3){Get-Random(1000-$t)}}` to `elseif($t-ne 1e3){Get-Random(1000-$t)}`? I see you've used an `elseif` earlier in your code, so this should save you 2 bytes. Also, maybe [Tips for golfing in Powershell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/191/52210) or [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5285/52210) might give some inspiration for more? Enjoy your stay! :)

Comment: totally correct about the ifelse. Removed its else counterpart earlier in the process. Link gave some inspiration too!

Answer (score 2):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), <s>192</s> 190 bytes

```pascal
var n,a:word;z:array[0..4]of word;begin read(n);if n>44then a:=a+3;if n>59then a:=a+2;Randomize;for n:=0to 999do inc(z[random(a)]);for n:=0to 4do if z[n]>0then writeln(z[n])else writeln end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcxBDoIwEEDRq8yyjUqIlkXbwCHcEhYjbbUJTkkhEnv5Khij25efP@LU43BwY5/zAyPQHtUSotFJYYz4bMuiEF1wsOHFXj1BtGgYce0dUCPEfLMEqGrcnT5UyR8d9RnJhLtPVrvw/qu6nANIKU0ATz1LbdwChrzj/4lYAweppa4pt@ES/WwHYitxO0z2K2DJFDmLqnoB)

Using [packing into bins method by TFeld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171985/60517). Prints bottom row first with a trailing newline.

It seems that FPC doesn't have problems with `random(0)`, so I have some unusual adding there.

---

My original submission, golfed down to 209 bytes:

```pascal
var n,i,a,r:int32;begin read(n);if n>44then a:=a-2;if n>59then a:=a-2;r:=1000;Randomize;for i:=-3to-0do begin if i>a then begin n:=random(r+1);if n>0then write(n);r:=r-n;end;writeln;end;if r>0then write(r)end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5LDsIwDAWvkmURDUp/CxKlh@AGpknBUnEqE4HE5UtIWMDOGr959gr3CRY5r9O2PYAF1VhDzRopdq05@wuSYA@uop3BWdDY9/HqSYC2INuChuMvYm0bpZQ5Ablww5c3c2CB2souBqlcEKU1qTiCyGohpC1nqeJ98z2n8v7JGP3nhVTOkownZzJbypyi/BflXcKHbeuH4Q0)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>113</del> <del>108</del> <del>99</del> <del>97</del> 93 bytes

```php
<?php $i=$argv[1];while($a++<1e3){${r.rand(1,$i<60?$i<45?:3:5)}++;}echo"$r5
$r4
$r3
$r2
$r1";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0BBJdNWJbEovSzaMNa6PCMzJ1VDJVFb28Yw1VizWqW6SK8oMS9Fw1BHJdPGzMAeSJqY2lsZW5lq1mprW9emJmfkK6kUmXKpFJkAsTEQGwGxoZL1////TQ0MAA)

-11 bytes thanks to @titus
-9 bytes because everything is a string

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 28 bytes

```
>“,;‘SḤ‘µȷŻṗS⁼¥ƇȷX;0ẋ5¤ḣ5Yḟ0
```

A full program printing the result (upside down, as has been allowed).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUEAvv9qZWxsef//PuKAnCw74oCYU@G4pOKAmMK1N8W74bmXU@KBvMKlxoc3WDsw4bqLNcKk4bij4bmaWeG4nzD///81OQ)** - this is altered to use `7` rather than `ȷ` (1000) because the implementation is golf-tastically slow! (...for \$n>59\$ a list of \$10^{15}\$ 5-tuples is built and then filtered, from which to choose)

#### How?

```
>“,;‘SḤ‘µȷŻṗS⁼¥ƇȷX;0ẋ5¤ḣ5Yḟ0 - Main Link: integer, n
 “,;‘                        - list of code-page indices = [44,59]
>                            - greater than? (vectorises)
     S                       - sum (i.e. 0, 1 or 2)
      Ḥ                      - double (i.e 0, 2 or 4)
       ‘                     - increment (i.e. 1, 3 or 5)
        µ                    - start a new monadic link, call that x (i.e. f(x))
         ȷ                   - literal 1000
          Ż                  - zero-range = [0,1,2,...,1000]
           ṗ                 - Cartesian power (all tuples of length x using those numbers)
               Ƈ             - filter keep if:
              ¥              -   last two links as a dyad:
            S                -     sum
             ⁼  ȷ            -     equals 1000? (i.e. only valid tuples)
                 X           - random choice (get one of these tuples)
                      ¤      - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                   0         -   zero
                    ẋ5       -   repeat five times = [0,0,0,0,0]
                  ;          - concatenate     (e.g. [354,388,258,0,0,0,0,0])
                       ḣ5    - head to index 5 (e.g. [354,388,258,0,0])
                         Y   - join with newlines
                          ḟ0 - filter out zeros
                             - implicit print
```

Comment: "_You are also allowed to reverse the output (I.e. `1000\n\n\n\n` instead of `\n\n\n\n1000` or `[87, null, 913, null, null]` instead of `[null, null, 913, null, 87]`)._" So yes, you are allowed to use the 28-byte version without the `Ṛ`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>37</s> 36 bytes

```
Ｆ²Ｆ²⊞υ∧‹³⁺ι÷Ｉθ¹⁵‽⊕⁻φ↨υ¹⊞υ⁻φΣυＥυ⎇ιＩιω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LCsIwEEX3fsUsJxCh9bEQVz42BQtF/YHQjDTQTjWPil8fm0rB2dzFnHtP3Shb96qN8dFbwJWAOavgGgwSDqzxQs7hWkLVBodGQsH@bAajCU/KeXwJCflWiDGuinXfYcG1pY7Yk8bS8NjKsyyTcFSO0mguptsvZss/dAsdht/XGvZYqmdC7mRZ2U/yT1Yz6t4Ji3Gzi8uh/QI) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 1 byte by converting the empty list from base 1 instead of trying to sum it. Explanation:

```
Ｆ²Ｆ²
```

Loop twice, twice. Alternatively I could have integer divided the loop index by 2 for the same byte count.

```
‹³⁺ι÷Ｉθ¹⁵
```

If the outer index plus a fifteenth of the temperature is greater than three...

```
⊞υ∧...‽⊕⁻φΣ∨υω
```

... then push a random integer up to and including 1000 - the sum so far. Unfortunately Charcoal can't calculate the sum of an empty list so I have to convert from base 1 instead.

```
⊞υ⁻φΣυ
```

Push the leftover amount to the list. (The sum is safe here because the list is no longer empty.)

```
Ｅυ⎇ιＩιω
```

Convert the list to string, but use the empty string instead of zero.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 62 bytes

```perl6
{($!=1e3)||@,|((+$!-($!-=$!.rand+|0)||@)xx($_/15+|0)*2-4)[^4]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1pDRdHWMNVYs6bGQadGQ0NbRVEXKKRrq6KoV5SYl6JdYwCS0qyo0FCJ1zc0BfG1jHRNNKPjTGJr/6flFykY6Bga6JgAkamOqYGOmYGOuYFCNZeCQnFipYJKvIKtnYIe0C6uWq7/AA)

An anonymous code block that takes a string and returns a list of integers, with `Nil` or an empty list (`[]`) in place of `0`s.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{($!=1e3)||@,|((+$!-($!-=$!.rand+|0)||@)xx($_/15+|0)*2-4)[^4]}
{                                                            }  # Anonymous code block
 ($!=1e3)  # Initialise $! to 1000
                +$!-($!-=$!.rand+|0)     # Pick a random value from 0 to $!
                                    ||@  # Or an empty array if it is zero
            ,  (                       )xx  # Repeat this
                                          ($_/15+|0)*2-4  # The given value mapped to 0,2,4
             |(                                         )[^4] # Get the first four values
 ($!    )||@  # Where the first value is the leftover number in $! or an empty array
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/), 126 bytes

This was an actually fun challenge!

This code creates a macro that has to be imported.

```
{%macro a(s,z=1000)%}{%for _ in 4..1%}{%set t=s>59or(s>44and _<3)?random(z):''%}{%set z=z-t%}{{t}}
{%endfor%}{{z}}{%endmacro%}
```

To import it, just do this:

```
{%- import 'macro.twig' as a -%}
{{- a.a(50) -}}
```

This should do the trick.

You can try it on https://twigfiddle.com/t4dfgy
**Notice**: Due to the page removing whitespaces, I was forced to add an `-` at the end of the line, to prove that it is outputting the correct number of lines.

On a regular installation, you would just see the newlines without issues.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>56</s></sup> <sup><s>55</s></sup> <sup><s>54</s></sup> <sup><s>48</s></sup> <sup><s>43</s></sup> 40 bytes

```
5{.1e3(2<@-/\[,0,~[:\:~?@$~)2*1#.>&44 59
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Tav1DFONNYxsHHT1Y6J1DHTqoq1irOrsHVTqNI20DJX17NRMTBRMLf9rcnEVpRaWZhalKqjnleamFmUmq3MVJeal5OdmVqWqq3NxpSZn5CukKRjAGCYmcJYpjGUGlzU0MOD6DwA)

*-3 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog*

---

Another conceptually nice method that's a bit longer but guarantees perfectly uniform distribution over all possibilities, per [the method here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1276225/20688):

#### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 53 bytes

```
5$!.a:[:<@(+/);._1 0:,(1e3#1)({~#?#)@,0$~2*1#.>&44 59
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/TVUU9RKtoq1sHDS09TWt9eINFQysdDQMU42VDTU1quuU7ZU1HXQMVOqMtAyV9ezUTEwUTC3/a3JxFaUWlmYWpSqo55XmphZlJqtzFSXmpeTnZlalqqtzcaUmZ@QrpCkYwBgmppgsM7ispSXXfwA)

Comment: Isn't `$!.a:` just `{.`?

Comment: @FrownyFrog Thanks.  I had forgotten that taking more elements than are available results in "zero" fill.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>115</s> <s>105</s> 98 bytes

<sup>-17 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
$a=,0*5
45,60-ge"$args"|%{$i+=2}
$i..4|%{$t+=$a[$_]=random(1001-$t)}
$a[4]+=1e3-$t
$a|%{"$_"*!!$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcq7CoMwGEDhPU@h4W9tvRHbqCBk6tK5SwcRDRgvELVEoYP12dP0Mp6P85ieQs2dkFJDw1YNnPnEjRGN/YQErcDAVTvj126F3mOnDUEfhvSTi8eA51AWTPGxnoZDREgUwHI0D89p4bFInE2bMjuGEru2DeWmN@Rcul7KzEF7aCxKEcLVeOdqyPBPkq/cRG1dp@WPaarf)

A golf of [Edwin's lovely answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172142/78849). If you like this, upvote him.

Comment: nice. a bit more golf [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcpPC4IwHMbx@16Fjl/pNGXWVBB26tK5S4cQGzgx2FTWoIP52m305/Z8PzzT@JTm0UulVuj4vE7CCB2CJiD4jkY5CveRy0RZlpP4vwtKSJqy12YGG3MQV2hqbsTQjjrMKM0SsGRBzlkd80weXLtydwwNjnwfmmVdUHDs70pVAdpC5zGGEL4NF2F0hb9SfOQsW@802h@W5foG "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: golf again [98 bytes](https://tio.run/##Lcq7CoMwGEDhPU@h4W9tvRHbqCBk6tK5SwcRDRgvELVEoYP12dP0Mp6P85ieQs2dkFJDw1YNnPnEjRGN/YQErcDAVTvj126F3mOnDUEfhvSTi8eA51AWTPGxnoZDREgUwHI0D89p4bFInE2bMjuGEru2DeWmN@Rcul7KzEF7aCxKEcLVeOdqyPBPkq/cRG1dp@WPaarf "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>62</s> 55 bytes

```ruby
->n{w=1000;[4,4,3,3].map{|r|r*15>n||w-=q=rand(w);q}<<w}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nco7CoAgAADQvVM0VmgofkBKLyIORrglJYREdnYjtOktL5zLlZ3MUPk7SowQmjQFFBBAzLjZ/U4hhQEz5VOKUB4yWL92sZ@OZ57jk/fWaWSaD1KltMqK7FcUeX0cF4Uw@QU)

Tests are limited to 0-99 degrees, because lava lamps could be [dangerous](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rjkvQo_FDQ) at higher temperatures:

Comment: Hi there. I'm afraid your answer is invalid. It currently has `0` for the empty lines. The empty lines in the array can be anything except for `0`, `false` or a negative number. So it can be `null`, `""`, `[]`, etc., but not `0`. Not sure if Ruby has object-arrays/lists so you can transform the `0`s to something else, but if not you'll have to print them instead of returning an array/list.

Comment: Fixed, but I think it's a little too arbitrary.